# appleid.apple.com will not loaded on Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, apple

I have tried to open appleid.apple.com on my Ubuntu 18.10 machine and I can not get it work right. I am getting a "502 Bad Gateway" error. I thought it was something on their end but the website works fine when I open it on my phone. I have tried to use Firefox, Google Chrome and Chromium with no luck.

Edit: Apple has fixed this issue after I reported it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like Apple is filtering on User Agent. I just switched mine to `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36` and it worked fine.

Comment: How did you switch it?

Comment: NVM, I used a Firefox extension called User-Agent Switcher and it worked!

Comment: Wow, this worked for me too.  Apple really sucks!!!

Comment: I reported this bug"(?)" to Apple. I really hope they fix this. It's really annoying since most websites don't play along nicely with User-Agent Switcher on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu and also with Mint Linux and tried out different browsers in that environments assuming the issue is only in a single environment.
The solution described above worked as well for me to install the Firefox AddOn called "UserAgentSwitcher" [https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher-revived/]

This gives a chance to simulates a certain environment. And It seems the Apple friends does not "like" the Linux community ;-)..

Every Linux based environment simulation lead to the 502 Bad Gateway issue - only other ones are working.
I do not have found an alternative also for other browsers so far...
Thanks for the trick.